# How do I identify apps or settings that cause performance problems?

Tags: performance, task-management, system-info

If I am having performance problems, what tools can I use to identify where my performance lags are coming from?  I have used a [System Panel Task Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/nextapp.systempanel.r1), [Android System Info](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.electricsheep.asi), [System Manager Free](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.droidappfactory.systemmanager) and some others but none of them have really identified the problem children.  System Panel Task Manager came the closest with it's historical look at CPU and memory usage but it didn't let me look at *which apps* were using how much resources over time.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Android 11 and up the security for controlling system dependent apps have been limited to root user only so modern android can do such automatically close unresponsive apps by default but if you run admin programs or debuggers it will interfere

How to activate Auto optimization
From Settings , swipe up and tap Battery & device care .
Tap More Options (three vertical dots) and then tap Auto Action .
Enable Daily Auto Optimize to automatically optimize your phone once a day.

Comment: *Starting from Android 11 and up the security for controlling system dependent apps have been limited to root user only*  -- Hi. Can you provide a link for this? I don't think root user should be involved in this at all.

Comment: Ah on latest android 13 y cant replicate that y use an app called 3c all in one toolbox (paied version) evething besids kernel settings works in none rooted devices task manager network,  battery settings including settings in the BSM board of the battery where you can set charge max ampere etc actually android 11 is kinda buggy but on android 13 you barely need root from anything  and if you really need to tweak root settings  you can use shizuku,  that supports some apps and acces the rootshell through wireless adb , and the saker app wich can reach root settings