# Prevent music player from closing while closing all apps

Tags: google-play-music

Is there a way to prevent the music player from closing while performing a clear all recent apps from the recent apps menu? I mean the app is technically in use so ideally it should not be closed along with the other apps. Is there any way to prevent this?

The app is Google Play Music if that is important.
Android ver: 4.4.4
Device: OnePlus One

Answer (score 3):

When you clear the "recent list", all related activities are "kindly asked to terminate" (see: [What actually happens when you swipe an app out of the recent apps list?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19987/16575)). So what you ask must basically be converted into "how to exclude an app from being removed from the recent list" – which I know no answer for.

In principle, "closing all apps" rarely is a good idea (except when shutting down the device, of course). It does no good to your battery (or anything else), as many of those apps will just "silently restart". If you have "performance issues", you should track them down to their cause (see e.g. [How do I identify apps or settings that cause performance problems?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/268/16575)) – and then stop the one app hogging those resources. Chuck-Norris-Roundhouse-Kicks in this case are like using atomics to kill a flie.

Comment: "It does no good to your battery (or anything else), as many of those apps will just 'silently restart'" and even the ones that don't will likely take more power to start next time you want them.

Comment: Thanks @DanHulme, I forgot to mention that part :) True that, because they've got to build up their entire "memory structures" again – which requires reading from storage (and possibly from network as well).

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question?

Comment: It explains why it is not possible, Alex. I felt that would be a bit more helpful than a simple "No".