# Vanilla Lollipop on Sony Xperia Z3?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sony-xperia-z3

I'm new to the Android camp (having used iOS for many years) and whilst there are many things I like about my Sony Z3, the performance isn't one of them. At its core my question is;

**Is it possible to install the vanilla version of Android Lollipop on my Z3, and revert back if needed?**

A bit of background.
Since getting the phone about a month ago, I have had the phone crash on me at least every couple of days, and whilst doing a variety of things. Sometimes when trying to open an app, and sometimes just trying to unlock the phone.

Additionally the overall performance seems sluggish for a 'flagship' phone compared to my iPhone 5S.

I don't have many additional apps outside of the pre-installed ones and they are all well known apps, I'd like to think.

I am hoping to remove the Sony version of Lollipop and replace it with a 'vanilla' version in the hope that the phone becomes a bit snappier due to not having to run all of the Sony stuff in the background.

Alternatively, **is there anything that can be done to speed up an Android phone, like how you can turn off some services in Windows?**

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154) – though your goal is identical with both, the approaches are completely different. Please [edit] your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way.

Comment: For the first part of your question, also see: [Is there an official Android “Google” ROM?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15717/16575) In short: unless someone built such a ROM, you cannot install it – ROMs are always device specific. So, next place to check: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575). For the second part, our [bloatware tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bloatware/info) might be a good start.

Comment: Also for the second part: [What are some general tips on improving overall performance of an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/3986/16575) / [How do I identify apps or settings that cause performance problems?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/268/16575) / other [questions using the `performance` tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance).